# Работа с Github и Bitbucket с одного компьютера

Tags: git, github, веб-программирование, bitbucket, git-push

Имеется ноутбук с установленным git 2.9.3. Есть аккаунт на **Github** и **Bitbucket**, зарегистрированный на один и тот же e-mail.

1. Могу ли я заливать одни проекты на **Github**, а другие **Bitbucket**?
2. И нужны ли дополнительные настройки при заливке на **Bitbucket**?

Comment: **1)** Вполне можете. Лично я заливаю одни проекты на GitHub, другие на BitBucket. Никаких сбоев в git, связанных с этим, не наблюдал, // **2)** Для заливки пользуюсь одинаковыми командами git. Отличий не замечаю. // Спасибо.

Comment: То есть для работы с Github, нужно клонировать репозиторий с Github, и так же для Bitbucket?

Comment: они же у вас в разных каталогах инициализированы) значит у каждого будет свой скрытый лог, и разный конфиг.

Comment: Вот спасибо) точно и ясно)

Comment: Более того, как на GitHub, так и на Bitbucket вы можете также заливать **один и тот же** репозиторий, просто настроив в своей локальной копии два *upstream* и выбирая конкретный с помощью `git push -u имя_репозитория` и `git pull -u имя_репозитория`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Заливка" (Отправление файлов и изменений из локального репозитория в удалённый) осуществляется по адресу, который указан в `remote` каждого локального репозитория.

Когда вы клонируете репозиторий с удалённого сервера (Github или Bitbucket) то в репозиторий устанавливается `remote` с именем `origin` в котором указан этот адрес. При `git push origin` файлы/изменения отправятся на удалённый репозиторий с указанным адресом.

При этом ничто не ограничивает вас в смене и добавлении других `remote`-ов. Т.е. вы можете склонировать репу с Github, поменять `remote` и пушить на Bitbucket. Или наоборот. А можете добавить ещё один `remote` для к-л репы и пушить и в Github и в Bitbucket.