# Как использовать git, чтобы хранить проекты на разных хранилищах?

Tags: git

Как использовать git, чтобы хранить две проекты на github и bitbucket? Не хочется ставить еще один клиент git.
Использую GUI-клиент GitHub, а также консольное окно github.

Comment: Кадется вам надо вот это: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/568508/17609

Comment: У вас проекты разные или вы их хотите хранить один и тот же репозиторий в разных местах?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы хранить один и тот же репозиторий на разных серверах вам не нужен другой клиент Git. Достаточно добавить их у себя в remotes:

```
git remotes add github https://github.com....
git remotes add bitbucket https://bitbucket.org....
```

И когда будете делать push/pull, дубрируйте для каждого remote:

```
git push github master;
git push bitbucket master;
```

И почитать [это](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8) в первую очередь.